# Why does Regex Replace delete a quote?

Tags: regex, eclipse

I'm trying to sanitize HTML tags, e.g. turn

```
 <input type="image" name="name" src="image.png">
```

into the correct empty-element form

```
 <input type="image" name="name" src="image.png" />
```

with a **slash** at the end.

I'm using Eclipse's Find/Replace with regular expressions like this:

*Find:* **<(input .*)[^/]>**

*Replace with:* **<\1 />**

But I end up with

```
 <input type="image" name="name" src="image.png />
```

I.e. the last quote is missing.

Is that an error in my regex, or a bug in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term `[^/]` is consuming the quote. Move it inside the captured group:

```
Find: <(input .*[^/])>

Replace: <\1 />
```

Comment: I was not aware that [^/] captures a character. I assumed that .* captures as much as it can get including the last quote, leaving nothing for [^/] to capture.

Comment: `.*` will consume as much as it can, but won't keep consuming if it means a match won't be found. In other words, it will consume as much as possible while still achieving a match. You should probably use `.*?` (reluctant) instead of `.*` (greedy), in case you have multiple `<input>` tags on the same line. If you do, `.*` will consume from the start of the first tag through to the end of the second tag - not what you want. Instead, `.*?` will consume as *little* as it can while still achieving a match.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your regex.  The `[^/]` at the end captures the last non-`>` character.  `\1` represents the first capturing group, which would be `(input.*)`.  In short, you are getting everything inside the tag except the last character.  If you put the `[^\]` inside your group, your replace should work.

<strike>Also, you may run into issues if you have a `/` inside of one of your attribute values.</strike>  **For performance reasons,**  I would recommend using the following regex:

`<(input [^/]*(/[^/]*)*)>`

In this case, it does not have to backtrack if you have a `/` inside of one of your attributes.  Your regex should capture everything you need though.

Comment: If he is doing find-replace in Eclipse, the "performance reasons" are most likely irrelevant.

Comment: Very true, although simple tweaks like the one I suggested are generally a good idea.  The regex skills you practice whilst writing find-replace regexes in Eclipse will be the same regex skills you end up using when writing regex strings in your applications.  In addition, depending on the number of files the user is searching, this could have a noticable effect on how long the operation takes.

Comment: I mainly wanted to point out that my original statement was incorrect (I left it in, but marked with strikethrough),  but that I still suggested the alternate regex.  At first glance I thought his statement would not capture those scenarios, but the greedy `.*` will work just fine.